# The property assigned to the stdClass() becomes empty after the function ends (global)

Tags: php, arrays, class, object

I'm trying to get the file names from the folder inside a folder ( there is a folder named `1` inside of `../merchant_assets/` folder and I'm trying to get all of the name files inside of that folder )

The code below works fine, however when I assigned my array that consist of the result `$temp` to the `stdClass()` variable `$container` it becomes empty when i try to print out the array outside of the function `print_r($container->screenshots)` but it works if i print it out inside of the function

```
<?php 
include 'config.php';

$url = "http://" . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . '/merchant_assets/';
$target = '../merchant_assets';

$merchant_id = 1;

$container = new stdClass();

$folder = '';

// Call the function
dir_contents_recursive($target);

// Get all screenshots images from merchant_assets folder based on merchant_id
function dir_contents_recursive($dir) {

    // open handler for the directory
    global $container;
    $iter = new DirectoryIterator($dir);
    $temp = Array();
    foreach( $iter as $item ) {

        // make sure you don't try to access the current dir or the parent
        if ($item != '.' && $item != '..') {

            if( $item->isDir() ) {

                // call the function on the folder
                global $merchant_id, $folder;

                if($merchant_id == $item->getFilename()) {

                    $folder =  $item->getFilename();
                    dir_contents_recursive("$dir/$item");
                }else 
                    continue;
            } else {

                // print files
                global $url, $folder;
                $current_index = count($temp);
                $temp[$current_index] = $url . $folder . '/' . $item->getFilename();
            }
        }
    }
    $container->screenshots = $temp;

    print_r($container->screenshots); // It shows the results
}

// Handle response
$response = $container;

print_r($container->screenshots); // No results???

$response_json = json_encode($response);
echo $response_json;
?>
```

I expected the output to be 
[ I intentionally changed the value of each index to `item` ]

```
Array ( 
[0] => item 
[1] => item 
[2] => item 
[3] => item
```

Comment: you can't call $container outside the function

Comment: @fmsthird actually he can as the original definition of `$container` is outside the function. But I don't recommend using globals. Why don't you return the object from the function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is your recursive call not assign the data to `$temp`.

In the begin of your function you decleare `$temp = Array();` - but you never use global on him.

So the first time the function called, `$temp` is empty array and `if( $item->isDir() )` is TRUE so it gets to the **recursive**. In there you do add element to `$temp` and assign `$container->screenshots` (that way the prints goes well).

However, after you exit the recursive call you again assign `$temp` to `$container->screenshots` but in this scope `$temp` is **empty** array! (there for no result).

I strongly recomend not using global here but to return array of file as the recursive function return argument.